# The expression « se prendre une engueulade maison »

Tags: sens

> Ne dirait-on pas qu'elles viennent tous de **se prendre une engueulade maison** !

I’m not sure how to interpret the expression « se prendre une engueulade » as well as « une engueulade maison ». My guess:

> Oh boy, it looks like they all just **got scolded at home**! {verbally}
>
> Oh boy, it looks like they all just **got into a fight at home**! {verbally or physically}

Incidentally: Is the word "engueulade" commonly used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- ***Se prendre*** is colloquial for *recevoir, subir* ("**receive, undergo**".)
- *Une **[engueulade](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/engueulade)***  is derived from *engueuler*, from *gueule* ("animal's mouth/maw.") *Engueuler* is a colloquial and common term for *gronder/réprimander* ("**to scold**".)
- ***[Maison](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/maison)*** is used figuratively. It is here an invariable adjective and a short for *fait maison* ("**home made**") implying a good quality and carefully made product. *Maison* doesn't means the scold will happen at anyone's home.

Thus, ***se prendre une engueulade maison*** is **to receive a sharp scolding**. This is only verbal, no physical fight here.

*Maison* entry in the TLFi states:

> II. − Adj. inv. [En appos. avec valeur expressive valorisante]
>   …
>   − Fam. Particulièrement réussi, soigné. Blague, engueulade, gifle maison. Jacques arrache à la débauche le pauvre orphelin, c'est encore le sujet, et l'objet, d'une bagarre maison (Queneau, Loin Rueil, 1944, p. 43).[Pierre Sora] l'avait levée (...) à Tanger et, après un baratin maison, l'avait ramenée à Paname (Le Breton, Rififi, 1953, p. 47).

There is also *se prendre [un savon](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/savon/1)* with the same meaning.

Comment: Merci. So does "une engueulade maison" mean the same things as "une engueulade carabinée"?

Comment: @Ahalone-zee Why not but carabinée is usually qualifying a disease or a fever.

Comment: @Ahalone-zee “Carabinée” wouldn't be used here, but I think you got the gist: here *maison* effectively acts as an intensifier. It's home-made, custom just for you, so you're going to feel it.

Comment: *Engueulade carabinée* is used too, e.g. *Cerise sur le gâteau, **engueulade carabinée** du président au téléphone parce que j'ai accordé une avance sur sa subvention à Libération.* Frédéric Mitterrand;

Comment: @Gilles Now it all falls into place! Is there another instance where the adjective "maison" serves as an intensifier? I get the feeling that you cannot attach it to just about any noun left and right. Merci.

Comment: You can't indeed. "*Maison*" is not exactly an intensifier, even less a generic one. As Gilles wrote, it "**plays the role**" of an intensifier here but it is not an adverb like would be French real intensifiers like *très*, *extrêmement*, *super*, *ultra*, etc. *Engueulade* is a noun so is less suitable to intensification like would be an adjective. *Maison* is here an invariable adjective qualifying "*engueulade*" and meaning "special" vs "regular, standard".

Answer (score 0):

"Se prendre une engueulade maison" means "to be right telling off". I hope that the pic will help you! :D
 [image]